# MeteorJS insert failed: Access denied

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Добрый день. При добавлении записи через браузер

```
Posts.insert({'title':123})
```

Получаю ошибку insert failed: Access denied

```
#/lib/collection.js

Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756863/meteor-mongo-insert-failed-access-denied

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вы удалили пакет insecure, который позволяет любому пользователю вставлять данные в базу данных. Это удобно для разработки, но недопустимо в продакшене.

Итак, вы должны создать метод для добавления данных в вашу базу.

Допустим, у вас есть форма в шаблоне fooTemplate:

```
//fooTemplate.html
<form name="fooForm">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок">
  <button type="Submit" value="Добавить">
</form>
```

fooTemplate.js:

```
Template.fooTemplate.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var title = $(event.target).find('[name=title]').val();
        if (title === "") {
            return console.log('Заголовок не может быть пустым');
        } else {
            Meteor.call('insertTitle', title); //Вызываем метод
            event.target.title = ""; //Очищаем форму
            //template.find("form").reset(); другой метод для сброса формы
        }
    }
})
```

В директории /server создаем server.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertTitle': function(title) {
        try {
            Posts.insert({
                title: title
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Возникла ошибка: " + error.reason); 
        }
    }
})
```

Так же вы можете создать правила allow/deny на клиенте. Подробнее тут: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow